# Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml found in C:\$Extend\$Deleted

Tags: windows, trojan, virus-removal

I am really worried right now. I got the following message from Defender (Windows 11):

[image]

**What I tried so far:**
Actions to remove or even quarantine don't work.

Defender offline scan, Malwarebytes, and MSERT didn't find anything but Defender full scan brought this up again.

Now, this folder is somewhat mysterious because no official information from Microsoft seems to exist. Even with "Show Hidden items" it cannot be accessed. And with CMD in admin mode, it just states that access is denied.

**My question:**
Could this be a false positive? On the other hand I encounter some strange stuttering of the system which I first thought would come from the Phone Link software.

Is there anything I can try besides setting up the system new? But even then other files could be infected and it would start all over again...

Thank you

**Update**
I scanned the computer from a clean Linux system with three different scanners (clamav, eset, and f-secure) with up-to-date signatures and nothing was found. Very strange indeed. Still don't know what to do.

**Update 2**
Now even a Defender full scan cannot find it. And I get the exact same message from above two (!) times! Very strange. Could it be that there is something wrong with the protection history?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151458/discussion-on-question-by-vonjd-trojanwin32-wacatac-bml-found-in-c-extend-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Files appear in `$Deleted` when they have an open handle but a request has been made to delete them ([link](https://dfir.ru/2020/03/21/the-extenddeleted-directory/)). Have you tried to reboot? This should get rid of them. For the stutter problem, we would need more information. Try to scan from inside Windows with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: I have a similar situation with a different Trojan:Script/Phonzy.A!ml. The threat is not there but I cannot get rid of the last weeks' "action needed" warning.

Comment: @harrymc: Have rebooted several times, to no avail. As I wrote above, no other scanner is able to find it.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to delete it from Linux?

Comment: @mcendu: the problem is that I haven't found a way to access this folder from Linux. Do you have an idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Detected: Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml
```

This is very often a false positive. In fact I can compile VB exes on my PC and Windows Defender will immediately try to delete/quarantine it with this detection. I have submitted such files to Microsoft and without exception got notification it was indeed a false positive.

Detection of such files is based on a very loose set of rules. A rule set could for example the combination of 2  hits from a set of 3 rules: (1) a generic type filename (SQOTT.exe for example), (2) absence of a digital signature and (3) the executable code being packed.

If it can not longer be found by Defender or other malware scanners the 'threat' if it ever actually was, is now gone.

It's very easy to find yourself victim of catch-22 type situations once Defender detected a suspicious file and you try getting rid of it but I don't think you have much to worry about this detection at this point.

To get rid of this file I suggest disable real-time monitoring > empty recycle bin > re-enable real-time monitoring.

If the file actually exists and as a last resort you can use the free version of DMDE disk editor.

Select the Drive then volume containing the file. > Now click Open Volume. The file you want is in the special MetaData folder. See if there, if so proceed to Deleting the file.

If not, click "All found / Virtual file system" > in dialog you should select Pure FS reconstruction and Include delete > OK. Now again check if the file you want to delete is present.

**Deleting the file.** Select the file > Tools > NTFS tools (write mode) > Remove file / empty directory .. Follow prompts to enable write mode.

Close DMDE and run chkdsk.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I just did a full scan. I see lots of NTFS entries with numbers. When I click on one of the arrows, it says "Opened volume will be closed. Continue?" How do I see the $deleted folder and its content?

Comment: No you DON'T do a full scan, the file either exists or it does not.

Comment: Is a full scan harmful? How do I find the file? Sorry, I don't find this program very intuitive.

Comment: full scan is not harmful but it will give you files that are not connected to file system. makes no sense to be deleting those. See my edits.

Comment: Not intuitive. Well, if you ever find a program that can edit file systems at this level AND is intuitive then let me know please.

Comment: Ok, I was in the wrong section, the second (logical disks) is the right one... the file is not there anymore. Thank you so much!

Comment: see harrymc's answer if Defender is stil complaining!

Answer (score 0):

[Virus:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Virus:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml&ThreatID=2147774417)
really is malware:

> This virus spreads by attaching its code to other files on your PC or network. Some of the infected programs might no longer run correctly.
>
> Microsoft Defender Antivirus detects and removes this program.

Defender has successfully detected and remediated the problem.
As the file was in use at the time, it was moved into the `$Deleted`
folder until the next reboot freed the open file-handle.

It could have been a false positive to start with, but prudence
dictates careful scanning of the system by multiple antivirus
products, as you did. You found nothing, but I suggest to
continue with periodical scanning as a precaution.

The file was probably removed after the next reboot and
no longer exists, as evidenced by the fact that it wasn't found in
subsequent scans, but the notification still remains
in Defender's detection history.

You can eliminate that false positive, by clearing
Defender's Protection History, like that:

- Boot Windows in Safe mode
- Run Explorer and navigate to:
  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service`
- Delete the sub-folder "Detection History" (or rename it
  temporarily as precaution)
- Reboot normally.

Windows will rebuild Detection History when
malware is next detected.

Comment: "really is malware:" .. Yeah DOH, but the detection is very often a false positive.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen: Who knows. The file no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you, another tool that I found quite helpful for clearing the protection history is DefenderUI.